# Using ets mnesia context for read-only operations

Tags: erlang, mnesia, ets

I have a mnesia `ram_copies` table replicated to all available nodes. Almost all operations using this table perform in dirty mode. What are consequences of using `mnesia:foldl` within `ets` context?

```
mnesia:activity(ets, fun() ->
  mnesia:foldl(fun(V, Acc) ->
      case V#my_table.field > 0 of
        true -> Acc;
        false -> Acc + 1
      end
    end, 0, my_table)
end).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have

- dirty transactions everywhere else, so you're not worried about synchronization
- ram_copies, so you don't care about checkpoints
- all tables replicated on all nodes, so all reads are local
- you are only reading, so remote nodes don't need to be notified

there's no difference in effect between `ets` and `async_dirty`. You may see some small speed improvement by bypassing a lot of tests that `async_dirty` does, but I wouldn't expect it to be a noticeable gain.

As a general practice, I'd recommend using one transaction type everywhere (defined as a macro), and only diverge when you've found real speed improvements. Otherwise you risk an error such as adding a write to your `ets` transaction or violating one of the other assumptions above, and then you're sunk.

Comment: But if I use transactions would reads within `ets` context be dangerous?

Comment: `ets` tells Mnesia to assume you're on a single ETS node. So if a different node had locked the table for writing, Mnesia will not respect the lock and you could get a partial read. That's not necessarily a disaster (maybe it's OK in your case to get a mangled read) but it's pretty confusing to read code that's both using and ignoring locks at the same time.